# How to remove or add querystring in vue without change the route?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

How to remove or add querystring in vue without change the render the components inside the route?

I want to do it when click on button:

```
onClick() {
 this.$route.params.add('key', value); //localhost:8080/?key=value
 this.$route.params.add('name', value); //localhost:8080/?key=value&name=value
 this.$route.params.remove('key') //localhost:8080/?name=value
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Inside your `onClick` method, first update the query object, and then push it to the `$router`:

```
onClick() {
  const query = this.$route.query;

  // add key
  query.key = value;

  // delete name
  delete query.name;

  this.$router.push({ query: query });
}
```

Comment: That means you're trying to navigate to the same location as you were before. If the query is different, that error shouldn't show up

Comment: This cause the components to re-render. for example it triggers `beforeRouteUpdate` which I don't want. just to replace/add/remove the querystring in the url..

Comment: @JonSud It's not actually re-rendering the component. If you add a `beforeUpdate` hook to your component, you'll see that doesn't fire. You are, however, updating the route, which should cause the `beforeRouteUpdate` to fire.

Answer (score 0):

```
onClick() {
  this.$route.query.key = value;   // localhost:8080/?key=value
  this.$route.query.name = value;  // localhost:8080/?key=value&name=value
  delete this.$route.query.key;    // localhost:8080/?name=value
}
```

This way you reactively change the $router query, without having to refresh the page

Comment: Everything on `this.$route` is supposed to be readonly, so this is not an ideal solution, if it even works

Answer (score 0):

I found this on Vue forum: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-remove-one-query-string-from-url/39176/3
The solution is to set up query param to undefined. But the problem is that param remains in the route object although it is removed from url.